# How check that the data in calendar textbox has changed with jquery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an ASP.NET MVC project. I have a calendar and I need to raise an event to active a button while I selected a date. I have written some event as below for this input but none of them had worked :

```
 let input = document.getElementById('Examples_0__ItemContent');

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
    alert("change");
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    alert("keyup");
});

input.addEventListener("drop", function () {
    alert("drop");
});

input.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("click");
});
```

How can I solve this problem?
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Did you check if the value of the `input` is not null after executing the first line.

Comment: Hello. No. Why?

Comment: Looks like autogenerate Examples_0__ItemContent. Check for any console errors first. Are you using any calendar plugin?

Comment: If the `input` variable has got null value then none of the following codes will work. Check if you have any console error. If you don't know how then add one more `if` condition to the code to check if the  `input` variable is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$('#Examples_0__ItemContent').on('change', function () {
   alert('change');
});
```

If above is not working, I suggest go with this one also once:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  alert('change');
});
```